# Why is limit 10 slower than limit 100？

Tags: database, postgresql

sql  limit 10 offset 0:

```
 EXPLAIN (analyze,buffers) SELECT
        jdry.c_bh AS rybh, 
        jcyq.c_bh,
        jdry.c_xm,
        jdry.c_jdrybm,
        jcyq.c_jdsbm,
        jcyq.c_bmbm,
        jdry.c_fq,
        jdry.c_fj
    FROM
        db_ggfw.T_JDRY jdry,
        db_szgl.T_JCYQ jcyq
    WHERE
        jdry.c_jdrybm = jcyq.c_jdrybm
    AND jcyq.c_sfyx <> '0'
    AND jcyq.c_dqspjg IS NULL
    AND jcyq.c_lx = '01'
    AND jcyq.c_dqspzt = '01'
    AND jcyq.c_jdsbm = '530104'
    ORDER BY
        dt_rssj DESC
    LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Results in this execution plan:

```
    Limit  (cost=0.84..2211.77 rows=10 width=124) (actual time=800.415..3228.545 rows=3 loops=1)
      Buffers: shared hit=729261
      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..126023.71 rows=570 width=124) (actual time=800.412..3228.534 rows=3 loops=1)
            Buffers: shared hit=729261
            ->  Index Scan using i_T_JDRY_dt_rssj on T_JDRY jdry  (cost=0.42..21059.54 rows=150163 width=73) (actual time=0.022..282.385 rows=150068 loops=1)
                  Buffers: shared hit=147487
            ->  Index Scan using i_jcyq_rybh on T_JCYQ jcyq  (cost=0.42..0.69 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=0 loops=150068)
                  Index Cond: ((c_jdrybm)::text = (jdry.c_jdrybm)::text)
                  Filter: ((c_dqspjg IS NULL) AND ((c_sfyx)::text <> '0'::text) AND ((c_lx)::text = '01'::text) AND ((c_dqspzt)::text = '01'::text) AND ((c_jdsbm)::text = '530104'::text))
                  Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                  Buffers: shared hit=581774
    Planning time: 0.896 ms
    Execution time: 3228.649 ms
```

limit 100 offset 0:

```
    EXPLAIN (analyze,buffers) SELECT
        jdry.c_bh AS rybh,
        jcyq.c_bh,
        jdry.c_xm,
        jdry.c_jdrybm,
        jcyq.c_jdsbm,
        jcyq.c_bmbm,
        jdry.c_fq,
        jdry.c_fj
    FROM
        db_ggfw.T_JDRY jdry,
        db_szgl.T_JCYQ jcyq
    WHERE
        jdry.c_jdrybm = jcyq.c_jdrybm
    AND jcyq.c_sfyx <> '0'
    AND jcyq.c_dqspjg IS NULL
    AND jcyq.c_lx = '01'
    AND jcyq.c_dqspzt = '01'
    AND jcyq.c_jdsbm = '530104'
    ORDER BY
        dt_rssj DESC
    **LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0**
```

Results in this execution plan:

```
    Limit  (cost=12365.88..12366.13 rows=100 width=124) (actual time=63.142..63.144 rows=3 loops=1)
      Buffers: shared hit=8810
      ->  Sort  (cost=12365.88..12367.31 rows=570 width=124) (actual time=63.139..63.139 rows=3 loops=1)
            Sort Key: jdry.dt_rssj DESC
            Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
            Buffers: shared hit=8810
            ->  Gather  (cost=1000.42..12344.10 rows=570 width=124) (actual time=20.764..63.104 rows=3 loops=1)
                  Workers Planned: 2
                  Workers Launched: 2
                  Buffers: shared hit=8810
                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..11287.10 rows=238 width=124) (actual time=43.906..57.953 rows=1 loops=3)
                        Buffers: shared hit=8524
                        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on T_JCYQ jcyq  (cost=0.00..9597.27 rows=238 width=68) (actual time=43.869..57.862 rows=1 loops=3)
                              Filter: ((c_dqspjg IS NULL) AND ((c_sfyx)::text <> '0'::text) AND ((c_lx)::text = '01'::text) AND ((c_dqspzt)::text = '01'::text) AND ((c_jdsbm)::text = '530104'::text))
                              Rows Removed by Filter: 43409
                              Buffers: shared hit=8512
                        ->  Index Scan using i_jdry_rybm_unique on T_JDRY jdry  (cost=0.42..7.09 rows=1 width=73) (actual time=0.061..0.063 rows=1 loops=3)
                              Index Cond: ((c_jdrybm)::text = (jcyq.c_jdrybm)::text)
                              Buffers: shared hit=12
    Planning time: 1.127 ms
    Execution time: 66.655 ms
```

limit 10 offset 0:T_jdry USES the index i_T_JDRY_dt_rssj.
limit 100 offset 0:t_jcyq seq_scan.

The execution plan is different when using limits 10 and 100, and limit 10 is very slow.

SQL is also fast when I remove the limit.
And when I delete the index i_T_JDRY_dt_rssj, it's pretty quick.

Comment: Choosing the wrong execution plan? why？

Comment: Did you run `analyze T_JCYQ`? Seems like estimates are very inaccurate for that table. If you did, you might need to try `SET STATISTICS` on columns used by query and see if increasing that value will get you better estimates.

Comment: I conducted the analyze vacuum and vacuum full

Comment: Then I would suggest to do a few SELECTs on `T_JCYQ` with each condition from where as a separate query and see when estimates are off, alter that column with increased statistics, do analyze again and see if it helps. CTE will only make postgres pick wrong (estimated) plan, because it does not consider LIMIT in optimization yet and you will fetch all (that match your WHERE) rows from that table, with is still slower than having Postgresql pick correct plan from the start.

Comment: I assume you don't need the formatted monkey hack any more - I'll delete it (as its not the answer)

Comment: I think you just got lucky: in the second plan the number of rows is **over**estimated. Making the nested loop cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

```
EXPLAIN  analyze
SELECT
    jdry.c_bh AS rybh,
    jcyq.c_bh,
    jdry.c_xm,
    jdry.c_jdrybm,
    jcyq.c_jdsbm,
    jcyq.c_bmbm,
    jdry.c_fq,
    jdry.c_fj
FROM
(select * from db_szgl.T_JCYQ jcyq1
WHERE jcyq1.c_sfyx <> '0'
AND jcyq1.c_dqspjg IS NULL
AND jcyq1.c_lx = '01'
AND jcyq1.c_dqspzt = '01'
AND jcyq1.c_jdsbm = '530104' order by dt_gxsj)
jcyq join 
    db_ggfw.T_JDRY jdry
on
    jdry.c_jdrybm = jcyq.c_jdrybm
ORDER BY jdry.dt_rssj DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0

Limit  (cost=16664.88..16664.90 rows=10 width=124) (actual time=70.415..70.417 rows=3 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=16664.88..16666.30 rows=570 width=124) (actual time=70.413..70.413 rows=3 loops=1)
        Sort Key: jdry.dt_rssj DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=12598.78..16652.56 rows=570 width=124) (actual time=70.355..70.396 rows=3 loops=1)
              ->  Sort  (cost=12598.36..12599.78 rows=570 width=7836) (actual time=70.295..70.296 rows=3 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: jcyq1.dt_gxsj
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                    ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..10654.27 rows=570 width=7836) (actual time=27.578..70.259 rows=3 loops=1)
                          Workers Planned: 2
                          Workers Launched: 2
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on T_JCYQ jcyq1  (cost=0.00..9597.27 rows=238 width=7836) (actual time=47.349..62.938 rows=1 loops=3)
                                Filter: ((c_dqspjg IS NULL) AND ((c_sfyx)::text <> '0'::text) AND ((c_lx)::text = '01'::text) AND ((c_dqspzt)::text = '01'::text) AND ((c_jdsbm)::text = '530104'::text))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 43410
              ->  Index Scan using i_jdry_rybm_unique on T_JDRY jdry  (cost=0.42..7.09 rows=1 width=73) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=1 loops=3)
                    Index Cond: ((c_jdrybm)::text = (jcyq1.c_jdrybm)::text)
Planning time: 2.276 ms
Execution time: 74.295 ms
```

Comment: This SQL I wanted to change its execution plan, because the results of the query itself is very small, only 3 data, sorting is not time-consuming, my goal is to add the sorting index change optimizer execution plan.